# User-generated account in JAVA FX

Tags: java, input, javafx, account

I am currently designing a little dice game that should involve a feature, which allows the user to create his own account by typing in a name and a password.

I've been thinking about using a constructor within the Account.java class, but i still haven't figured out how it is possible to permanently store user input so it is available the next time you run the application. How do I go about storing more than one piece of information (in this case username and password) in the same object?

Any advice? Does this type of class probably already exist in JAVA or JAVA FX?

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could always opt for an embedded solution, and since you are using Java you might want to give H2 a go: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4955598

Here is a Git project showing how to use H2: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: Ok thanks, that sounds like what I've been looking for. Just out of curiosity: Would it be possible to save the names in a simple .txt file and read the file whenever the application starts?

Comment: Oh Yes, definitely, but you might run into scalability and security issues.  

Essentially databases are just fancy text files with extra features, but the problem with rolling your own system is always the danger of running into a whole lot of problems that have allready been solved quite successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Database is what you need.

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48193

this is a tutorial with Postgresql and javafx.

Have at it!